# Completely transparent navigation bar

Tags: android, uinavigationbar, transparent

I tried to get a completely transparent navigation bar like this image from Google web:

[image]

I use this in my style:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Then my navigation bar is white, I put an image view that fill all screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2000dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But with this I only get this:

[image]

Is it possible to get? am I doing something bad? or is it just a bug?

Answer (score 5):

In your theme put this line:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

see here the [sample app](https://github.com/romainguy/google-io-2014)

Comment: That is a tranluscent navigation bar, I want a completely transparent navigation bar! Check the Google Image,

Comment: Really, it seems does  not possible to do this!

Answer (score 1):

in your onCreate function add

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window w = getWindow(); // in Activity's onCreate() for instance
        w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        w.setNavigationBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

In XML: values-v21 (inside the style used by your activity)

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Then if you want your content to not be under the nav bar use the following function to get the height of the navbar:

```
 private int getNavHeight() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then use it to add buttom padding to your main view

Comment: This seems to affect the status bar too. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to have a completely transparent nav bar but well if you *really* want it you can use the DrawerInsetsFrameLayout class which allow you to modify both the background of the nav and the status bar.
More info on this post: https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/T4FQkkJ5bGc

You'll just have to set a transparent color on your layout like this :

```
<FrameLayout>
        <ListView … /> <!-- or whatever else is your content -->
        <your.package.DrawInsetsFrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            yourapp:insetBackground="@android:color/transparent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I have to test it, when I get it working I will accept your answer!